# Исключить листы из обработки скрипта

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Есть скрипт, который автоматически ставит дату при изменении заданных ячеек на текущем листе. Нужно исключить несколько листов из обработки. Имя исключаемых листов к примеру "Лист 1", "Лист 2".

```js
function onEdit(event) {
  //SETTINGS
  // var tsheet = 'Январь 2017'; //лист на котором ты мониторишь изменеия
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var tsheet = event.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName() // Получаем имя листа который активен
  var lcol = 6; //номер самого левого столбца, а котором проверяются изменеия; A=1, B=2 и т.д.
  var rcol = 8; //номер крайнего правого столбца для проверки
  var tcol = 5; //номер колонки, в которой ты хочешь установить штамп со временем

  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var sname = s.getName();
  if (sname == tsheet) {
    var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
    var scol = r.getColumn();
    if (scol >= lcol && scol <= rcol) {
      s.getRange(r.getRow(), tcol).setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Решено изменением строки:

```js
function onEdit(event) {
  //SETTINGS
  // var tsheet = 'Январь 2017'; //лист на котором ты мониторишь изменеия
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var tsheet = event.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName() // Получаем имя листа который активен
  var lcol = 6; //номер самого левого столбца, а котором проверяются изменеия; A=1, B=2 и т.д.
  var rcol = 8; //номер крайнего правого столбца для проверки
  var tcol = 5; //номер колонки, в которой ты хочешь установить штамп со временем

  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var sname = s.getName();
  f (sname == tsheet && (sname != 'Лист 1' && sname != 'Лист 2')) {
    var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
    var scol = r.getColumn();
    if (scol >= lcol && scol <= rcol) {
      s.getRange(r.getRow(), tcol).setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
```